# What's more efficient?

Tags: c, function

What's more efficient? Why?

Option 1:

```
int n = someFunction();
for (int i = 0; i < n ; i++)
    //do something...
```

Option 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (someFunction()); i++)
    //do something...
```

Thanks in advance for the replies!

Comment: To see what the difference is, provide code for `someFunction` and then check the compiler's assembly output to compare the two options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former will always be at least as efficient as the latter. With the former, you're only evaluating `someFunction` once. With the latter, you're calling it on every single iteration.

A smart compiler might be able to inline the body of `someFunction` in the latter case and realize that it might be a constant, making it effectively equal, but the first one will never be slower.

Sometimes I do something like this, borrowing a convention from JavaScript:

```
for(size_t i = 0, l = someFunction(); i < l; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

This is effectively the same as the first version except a little more concise like the second.

Comment: A compiler would need to be super-smart to optimize the second option: when there is no guarantee that `someFunction()` returns the same value *and* is free of side effects, the compiler would not be able to optimize it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: If it just performed a calculation using a global variable and returned it with no side effects and the compiler knew the body of that function and the compiler could tell that the value of that global variable could not change during the loop, it could optimize it out.

Comment: Does gcc/clang perform this optmization?

Comment: @Jack: Yes, clang/LLVM does. [Here's my test case.](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ar2NvhYN) The generated assembly accesses the global variable and performs the division only once. It then uses that calculated value through the rest of the loop.

Answer (score 6):

The two loops are not even equivalent: in case `someFunction()` is expected to return different values when you call it multiple times, the results are going to be different.

When `someFunction()` returns the same value no matter how many times you call it, the first option is going to be more efficient when `someFunction()` returns a number greater than or equal to `1`. In case it returns `0`, there will be no difference.

The difference in timing comes from the fact that the second option calls `someFunction()` repeatedly in the loop to get the limit. Even if the function call is very fast, this code is sub-optimal

Comment: +1 - this and @JonathanLeffler's answer are the only two that seem to note that the two loops are different beasts regardless of efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

Option 1 makes fewer calls to `SomeFunction()` for the general case where `someFunction()` returns a value larger than zero on the first call.  It will be more efficient, therefore.

Option 2 cannot be optimized unless the compiler can see the body of `someFunction()` and can determine that it will always return the same value regardless of what happens in the `...do something...` code.

Answer (score 0):

First one is more efficient as it checks for someFunction only once. In second one, for every loop it checks for someFunction() over and over again

Comment: Thanks for the replies! I have a better idea now on how to deal with these kind of situations.

Answer (score 0):

If output of `someFunction()` doesn't change over time, then option 1 is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, syntax is wrong on option 1, the `for` loop is missing the right parentheses.  So that won't compile.

Second, option 2 is definitely more expensive, and potentially totally wrong, because you're calling `someFunction()` repeatedly, instead of calling it once and using the returned value to limit the.

Answer (score 0):

First one is efficient since its compare i with a constant to evaluate the for loop condition, however 2nd for loop evaluate the someFunction() every iteration.